# How to find in current directory to list all files whose owner is aa1, group is grp and it has not been accessed since last two years in unix?

Tags: shell, unix

Can any one suggest me how to  find in the current directory to list  all files whose owner is aa1, group is grp and it has not been accessed since last two years in unix.

Thanks in advance

Comment: good question! and +1 to anyone who can do this as a one-liner with 30 characters or less...

Comment: @vikingsteve Can I use `zsh`? `ls *(. u[aa1] g[grp] a+730)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find . -user $USER -group $group -atime +730`

Comment: And add `-mindepth 1` too. `-maxdepth 1` is also necessary if recursion is not intended.